# Rails nested forms - how to only submit the inner form when using form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, nested

Say you have nested forms in rails, which is only nested to accomodate the layout (in other words have nothing to do with each other, and should be submitted completely seperately)

for example

```
= form_tag update_custom_stock_admin_shop_products_path(@current_shop), method: 'put' do
 ...
 ...
 = form_tag change_range_admin_shop_products_path(@current_shop), remote: true do
   ...
   submit_tag 'change'
 ...
 ...
 submit_tag 'submit'
```

How do I ensure that only the inner form is submitted when the inner submit ('change') is clicked, and the same for the outer form.

And *please*, do not tell me to use `form_for` instead. Because I am using custom parameters and interpreting them manually with `params`. If you do not know the answer, I kindly ask that you ignore my question and do not downvote or tell me it's better to use `form_for`

Answer (score -1):

Nested forms don't really work. According to the html5 spec you shouldn't have them at all. You can have multiple forms per page though. You'll probably need to rethink the logic and use multiple remote forms.

Here's the html5 spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element. Note:

```
4.10.3 The form element
  Content model:
    Flow content, but with no form element descendants.
```